# Appending Elements with JQuery Removes Previous Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, append

I have a `ul` which gets appended several `li`s after an AJAX request. The previous elements in the list get removed, why is this?

*AJAX call function:*

```
var $comments = $('.comments').find('ul');

$comments.text('Loading...');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/',
        success: function(result){

            if (result == 0){
                $comments.text('No comments.');

                return;
            }                           

            $comments.text('');

            display_comments(result);
        }
    });
```

*List Display function:*

```
function display_comments(result){
var result_comments = JSON.parse(result);   

var $ul = $('.comments').find('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){

        // Insert comments
        lis += '\
            <li>\
                ' + comments[i].title + '\                  
                <p>' + comments[i].description +'\
            </li>';
    }

$ul.append(lis);
}
```

Comment: BTW what is ´comments.length´ ???  don't see any ´comments´ assignation ???

Comment: I also noticed that the `lis` var isn't declared anywhere (or if it is declared it must be somewhere outside the `display_comments` function).

Comment: @lorenzo Sorry, it's written correctly in the original code.

Comment: @JonathanNicol Yes, correct it is declared outside somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this

`$comments.text('Loading...');`

and this

`$comments.text('No comments.');`

and this

`$comments.text('');`

The reason this is happening is that the jQuery's `.text()` method overwrites the contents of the matched element. In the case of a `ul` its contents are any child `li`s. So when you start loading list items your `ul` becomes: `<ul>Loading...</ul>`

Comment: Ha! worked like a charm! So what is the reason is it resetting EVERYTHING inside the `ul`?